# SQL get counts using subqueries from multiple linked tables

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have tables 1-4, all the other tables are linked to table1. For what its worth, table1, table2 and table3 are relatively small but table4 contains a lot of data.

Now I have the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1_id = t1.id) AS t2_count
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE table1_id = t1.id) AS t3_count
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table4 WHERE table1_id = t1.id) AS t4_count
FROM table1 t1
```

Due to the fact that the subqueries are dependent/correlated I assumed that there must be a better way (performance wise) to get the data.

I tried to do the following but it drastically increased the execution time (from about 2s to 35s). I'm guessing that the multiple left joins creates a very big data set?!

```
SELECT t1.id
    , COUNT(t2.id) AS t2_count
    , COUNT(t3.id) AS t3_count
    , COUNT(t4.id) AS t4_count
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.table1_id = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.table1_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Is there better way to get the counts? I don't need the data from the other tables.

**UPDATE:**

Bart's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743288) got me thinking that the `table1_id` columns are nullable. I added a `IS NOT NULL` check to the `WHERE` clauses and this brought the time down to 1s.

```
SELECT t1.id
   , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1_id IS NOT NULL AND table1_id = t1.id) AS t2_count
   , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE table1_id IS NOT NULL AND table1_id = t1.id) AS t3_count
   , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table4 WHERE table1_id IS NOT NULL AND table1_id = t1.id) AS t4_count
FROM table1 t1
```

Comment: you mean `increase` rather than `reduced` the execution time right ?

Comment: Indeed, I fixed it. (_reduced the performance_ changed to _increased the execution time_)

Comment: I hope there are indexes on `table1_id` in each of the tables. If not, create them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not. If you execute a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table]`, it should perform a count on the table's PK. That should be pretty fast, even for very large tables.

Is your `table4` a real table (and not a view, or a table-valued function, or something else that looks like a table)? And does it have a primary key? If so, I don't think that the performance of a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table4]` query can be increased significantly.

It may also be the case, that your `table4` is heavily targeted (in concurrent transactions over multiple connections), or perhaps your SQL Server is doing some heavy IO or computations. I cannot assume anything about that, however. You may try to check if your query is also slow on a restored database backup on a physically separate test server.

Comment: Yes, `table4` is a real table, with a primary key. 

That got me thinking that the `table1_id` column is nullable and that the majority are in fact null. I added a `table1_id IS NOT NULL AND table1_id = t1.id` to the query and this brought the time down from 3s to 1s.